# limit results for wpdb query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

this code displays the tags from current category only but, it gets all the tags (hundreds) so, i need to limit the number of returned results and make em random.

How to make this query get only 20 results randomly ?

```
/* Retrieve all tags from posts in selected categories */

$cats = array('beaches','mountains');  // Must be an array even if only one category
$cats_string = "'" . implode($cats,"','") . "'";
$sql = <<<EOSQL
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM $wpdb->posts p
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
   AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag')
JOIN $wpdb->terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE
   p.ID IN (
      SELECT p2.ID
      FROM $wpdb->posts p2
      JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr2 ON p2.ID = tr2.object_id
      JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt2 ON (tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id     AND tt2.taxonomy = 'category')
  JOIN $wpdb->terms t2 ON (tt2.term_id = t2.term_id AND t2.name IN ($cats_string))
  WHERE p2.post_type = 'post'
  AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
  AND p2.post_date <= NOW()
  )
  EOSQL;

$terms = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

// print_r($terms);

echo "<br />";
foreach ($terms as $term) {
   echo "ID:$term->term_id NAME:$term->name SLUG:$term->slug<br />";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try an `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20`, depending on your table size this can run in decent times. See [here](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql) some details on when to avoid the `order by rand()` logic. Like suggested, in the specified post, the other approach is to retrieve all the entries and randomly select 20 entries, in PHP rather then using mysql.

Comment: thanks for your help, after some trial and errors i could place the parameters in right position and it works now :)